# angular 2: ngIf problems

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I got an angular 2 project where a canvas class (build in typescript but outside of the actual angular 2 application) triggers an event whenever the current animation on the canvas was finished. This is performed by the following basic event listener/dispatcher structure:

**canvas.ts**

```ts
eventListener = [];

public addListener(name : string, cb : Function) {
        this.eventListener.push({name: name, cb : cb});
}

public dispatchEvent(name : String, event) {
        var scope = this;
        $.each(scope.eventListener, function(key, value){
            if(value.name == name) {
                value.cb(event);
            }
        });
}
```

The event listener is registered in one component:

**component-that-listens.ts**

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.canvasHelper.addEventListener('animationFinished', () => this.handleAnimationEnd());
}

private handleAnimationEnd() {
    this.isPlaying = false;
    this.isPaused = false;
}
```

As the component the canvas is in and the one the view should be updated when the animation is done are sibling components there is a `canvasHelperService` handling the communication of those two.

In the listening component there is an ngIf structure to switch the appearance of a button according to the current status of the animation (stopped, finished, paused, running). This is handled by the boolean variables `isPaused` and `isPlaying` in a simmilar way to this:

```html
<span *ngIf="!isPlaying" (click)="play()">PLAY ICON</span>
<span *ngIf="isPlaying" (click)="pause()">PAUSE ICON</span>
```

If these are both reset to `false` the initial state should be restored. This all actually works just fine. However, it only resets the button to show the play icon as soon as I hover over the canvas and I can't find a reason why this would happen.

How can I force the ngIf to instantly react to the current animation state without me having to hover over the canvas (part of the component dispatching the event)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess change detection works not properly for you. The `animationFinished` event might not be dispatched in the correct NgZone. To fix this you can use NgZone.run as shown here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.canvasHelper.addEventListener('animationFinished', () =>
    this._ngZone.run(() => this.handleAnimationEnd()));
  }
}
```

Alternatively check that your eventdispatcher is created inside the NgZone (it usually is when it's created through the angular2 dependency injection mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that your event listener callbacks are not running in the `NgZone` when using `$.each`. You could use the default `Array.prototype.foreach` to cycle through the listeners:

```ts
this.eventListener.forEach(listener => {
    if(listener.name == name) {
        listener.cb(event);
    }
}
```